# What is the C3.JS color.pattern property for?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I'm hoping the color.pattern array allows the code to specify the color of each dot on the chart, but given this example I'm not sure it even does anything:

http://c3js.org/samples/options_color.html

What does it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial guess was more or less correct. You can use it to set the colors of each line on the chart.

The array can be longer than the actual number of data `columns` - if there were more data arrays in that example, the unused colors would have been used.

Comment: So it's a per-line setting, not per-dot setting?

Comment: Exactly. I don't think you can make each individual dot a different color. (By the way, I had understood your initial assumption incorrectly and changed my answer to reflect that)